# Há alguma forma do loop rodar para cada repetição numa tabela?

Tags: python, pandas, loop, selenium-webdriver, dataframe

Estou montando um script no Selenium pelo Python. Através do loop, ele lê cada linha de uma tabela em excel e preenche um cadastro numa página web com informações de colunas específicas.

Segue tabela para exemplo:

```
oc = [['1', '13/10/2022', 'joao', '1000'],
     ['1', '28/10/2022', 'maria', '2000'],
     ['2', '13/10/2022', 'marcos', '3000'],
     ['2', '13/10/2022', 'marcos', '4000'],
     ['3', '16/09/2022', 'joao', '1500'],
     ['3', '18/10/2022', 'maria', '2500'],]
df = pd.DataFrame(oc, columns=['Requisicao', 'data solicitacao', 'medico solicitante', 'valor'])
```

Utilizo o loop abaixo para efetuar um cadastro na página para cada linha dessa tabela:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    data = chrome.find_element(By. XPATH,'.//')
    data.send_keys(row['data solicitacao'])
    valor = chrome.find_element(By. XPATH,'.//')
    valor.send_keys(row['valor'])
```

Porem preciso que as linhas com a mesma numeração de **Requisição** (Ex. '1', '1' ou '2', '2') sejam inseridas no mesmo cadastro durante a automatização.

Há alguma forma do loop rodar para cada repetição na coluna "**Requisição**"?

Comment: Qual é o comportamento desejado? Substituir pelo segundo? Ignorar o segundo e deixar o primeiro?

Comment: Você pode agrupar seus dados por requisição usando groupby, por exemplo: `for n_requisicao, df_requisicao in df.groupby('Requisicao'): print(n_requisicao, df_requisicao)`. A lógica do que fazer com cada `df_requisicao` vai depender do quê exatamente você precisa fazer na página web.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, @jfaccioni. Obrigado!

Utilizei dois loops. Um com o 'groupby' e o outro com 'iterrows' .

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Complementando o comentário de [jfaccioni](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/147228/jfaccioni).

Você provavelmente precisará de um *nested loop*

```
for req, item in df.groupby("Requisicao"):
    # item é do tipo DataFrame
    for index, row in item.iterrows():
        # row é do tipo Series
        print(row)    # Substitua estas duas linhas pelo o que você
        print("---")  # precisa para o cadastro.
```

No exemplo acima, a saída será.

```
Requisicao                     1
data solicitacao      13/10/2022
medico solicitante          joao
valor                       1000
Name: 0, dtype: object
---
Requisicao                     1
data solicitacao      28/10/2022
medico solicitante         maria
valor                       2000
Name: 1, dtype: object
---
Requisicao                     2
data solicitacao      13/10/2022
medico solicitante        marcos
valor                       3000
Name: 2, dtype: object
---
Requisicao                     2
data solicitacao      13/10/2022
medico solicitante        marcos
valor                       4000
Name: 3, dtype: object
---
Requisicao                     3
data solicitacao      16/09/2022
medico solicitante          joao
valor                       1500
Name: 4, dtype: object
---
Requisicao                     3
data solicitacao      18/10/2022
medico solicitante         maria
valor                       2500
Name: 5, dtype: object
---
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado, Paulo!